# WP HTTP Error: Couldn't resolve host

Tags: domain-name-system, debian, wordpress

I keep getting this kind of error in my WP dashboard:

```
WP HTTP Error: Couldn't resolve host
```

I tend to believe it's a DNS issue although all was working OK before.
What I have done is altering the /etc/hosts file and adding stuff like:

```
127.0.0.1               localhost.localdomain localhost
188.116.55.217          zako.vladoiu.net zako
72.233.56.139 api.wordpress.org
72.233.69.6 jetpack.wordpress.com
72.233.56.138 downloads.wordpress.org
72.233.56.138 jetpack.wordpress.org
72.233.69.89 rest.akismet.com
72.233.69.88 rest.akismet.com
66.135.58.62 rest.akismet.com
66.135.58.61 rest.akismet.com
173.194.70.109 smtp.gmail.com
76.74.254.123 dashboard.wordpress.com  
173.194.65.106 blogsearch.google.com
173.194.*.* google.com
```

While this fixes the error say :

```
WP HTTP Error: Couldn't resolve host 'rest.akismet.com'
```

Answer (score 1):

Put valid DNS server entries into `/etc/resolv.conf`.

It should look something like this:

```
nameserver 203.0.113.187
nameserver 198.51.100.32
nameserver 2001:db8:24fe:381::37
```

The actual values will be supplied by your ISP, hosting provider or datacenter. Or you can use public DNS providers such as [Google Public DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using).

Comment: Ha,thanks a bunch! I am using a freeDns service: fns2.42.pl & fns1.42.pl - i'll just take the IP's and put there. Thank you!

Comment: Those don't look like normal recursive DNS servers. They probably aren't.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your /etc/resolv.conf file on server:

nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4

Should solve your issues.